# Use _.first function from lodash in my provider?

Tags: javascript

I have provider which parameters are $scope and HTMLElement. I use .find to find element in css and I want push first parameter from css.

My code which work

```
new GoogleProvider(this.$scope, this.$element.find('.map-container')[0], () => {
                this.onMapReady()
            })
```

and i must use _.first(), something like that?

```
new GoogleProvider(this.$scope, this.$element.find('.map-container')._first(), () => {
                this.onMapReady()
            })
```

Comment: Have you somehow attached Lodash to the elements? Because usually you would do `_.first(someElement)` not `someElement._first()`

Comment: If you want to get the native element, you can use `.get(0)` from jQuery (I assume you use it)

Comment: Ok i use ._first(this.element) but how refer to '.map-container'

Comment: I'm guessing you need to do sth like: `_.first(this.$element.find('.map-container'))`

Comment: I used it but didn't work, ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined```